# analogue webkit-transform in opera

Tags: css, transform, opera

I have in my code this properties.

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(65deg);
//or
transform: rotateY(65deg);
```

This works on IE and on FireFox. I need, that it also works on Opera. I can not find a property for the opera. Is there any analogue of such property on opera?

This is my all code:

```
    body {
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

#trapezoid {
  background-image: url("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-D9i-wqTIjFw/T5x_51p2rJI/AAAAAAAABLs/VytuZcJGNuY/s400/indahnya.jpg") ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(65deg);
  transform: rotateY(65deg);
  width: 5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the property you want to use is a [CSS3 3D transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-property) property.

Note that W3C puts it in the *15.2. 3D Transform Functions section*.

> **rotateY()**
>       same as rotate3d(0, 1, 0, ).

As [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) and [Mozilla Network Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) tell us, Opera don't support this now, (but probably do in the future).

EDIT: If you don't mind to use jQuery I found this plugin, [Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/),  that claims it can do CSS3 Transforms!

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer...

`-o` is Opera's vendor prefix, however it seems that `-o-transform: rotateY(65deg)` does not work since older Opera did not supported 3d transform.

However latest version, Opera Next, using Blink probably supports `-webkit-transform: rotateY(65deg`

Comment: Both answers were wrong since the latest version works with -webkit. Not a fixed answer. Its a matter is version